# error: The argument type '() → Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type '(Null) → FutureOr<dynamic>'

Tags: dart, flutter

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:camera/camera.dart';


    class Register extends StatefulWidget{
      List<CameraDescription> cameras;
      @override
      _Register createState() {
        return _Register();
      }

      Register(this.cameras);
    }

    class _Register extends State<Register>{

      CameraController controller;

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context){
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Registration Certificate',
          home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: new Text('Register'),
            ),

          body: Container()
          ),
        );
      }


      @override
      void initState(){
        super.initState();
        controller = new CameraController(widget.cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.medium);
        //**SYNTAX ERROR from the below code**
        controller.initialize().then(() {});
      }
    }
```

**ERROR DETAILS**

> error: The argument type '() → Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type '(Null) → FutureOr'. (argument_type_not_assignable at [fluttercam] lib\packs\reg.certificate.dart:38)

When I use '_' underscore the code is working fine, *Error resolved!*

```
controller.initialize().then((_) {});
```

*Can anyone explain what is going on behind the scenes?*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When a function that takes a parameter is expected,

```
(Null) → FutureOr<dynamic>
```

you can't pass a function that accepts none

```
() → Null
```

`_` is a valid parameter name and is by convention used to indicate that the parameter is not used and makes the passed function compatible with the defined parameter type because it now accepts a parameter.

`controller.initialize()` returns a `Future` and the `then(...)` method expects a function that it calls when the async task is completed and the result of the completed async task is passed as a parameter to that callback function.

https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-async/Future/then.html shows the parameter definition for `then`:

```
FutureOr<R> onValue(T value)
```

which is a function that accepts a parameter of the generic type `T` and returns a value of `FutureOr<R>`

Comment: Thanks for your quick response @Günter Zöchbauer, Can you please explain what is the use of it?

Comment: The use of what? I thought I explained what `Future.then` is for. You pass a function that `Future` calls when the async task is completed. https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures might help.

Comment: I mean the parameter we are passing. for example '_' underscore

Comment: Many thanks for your warm response @Günter Zöchbauer

Comment: There is nothing about it. You can change it to `foo` and it will do the same.